# MongoDB - aggregate in 2 collection

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a 2 collections.

**The first of the collections: 'firmaListesi'**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58455d2d506c1cab1c82153c"),
    "value" : {
        "firmaid0" : ObjectId("58455d92506c1cab1c82153e"),
        "firmaid1" : ObjectId("5847afe2506c912e6e3a72a7"),
        "firmaid2" : ObjectId("5850f2e725108a44a813f93f"),
        "firmaid3" : ObjectId("58523f272510fae3c1345547")
    }
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58455d2d506c1cab1c82154c"),
    "value" : {
        "firmaid0" : ObjectId("5850f2e725108a44a813f93f"),
        "firmaid1" : ObjectId("58523f272510fae3c1345547")
    }
}
```

**The second of the collections: 'calisanSayisi'**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58455d92506c1cab1c82153e"),
    "value" : 13.0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5850f2e725108a44a813f93f"),
    "value" : 1.0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58523f272510fae3c1345547"),
    "value" : 3.0
}
```

I want to be in relationship with 'calisanSayisi._id' and 'firmaListesi.value.firmaid'. I want to combine two collections in this way. There is an error in the code I wrote. But for 1 area this works. You can see what I want better in the picture. I want to make a picture for all the fields.

**My Result**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58455d2d506c1cab1c82153c"),
    "value" : {
        "firmaid0" : ObjectId("58455d92506c1cab1c82153e"),
        "firmaid1" : ObjectId("5847afe2506c912e6e3a72a7"),
        "firmaid2" : ObjectId("5850f2e725108a44a813f93f"),
        "firmaid3" : {
            "_id" : ObjectId("58523f272510fae3c1345547"),
            "value" : 3.0
        }
    }
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58455d2d506c1cab1c82154c"),
    "value" : {
        "firmaid0" : ObjectId("5850f2e725108a44a813f93f"),
        "firmaid1" : ObjectId("58523f272510fae3c1345547")
    }
}
```

**My Code:**

```
function birlestir(a,b) {
    db.firmaListesi.aggregate([
        {$lookup: {
            from: "calisanSayisi",
            localField: a,
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: a
        }},
        {$unwind: {path: b, preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true}},
        {$out: "firmalarId"}
    ]);
}
for(var i=0; i < (Object.keys(db.firmalistesi.value).length); i++){
    var a = 'value.firmaid'+i;
    var b = '$'+a;
    birlestir(a,b);
}
```

There are major faults in the code. But I can not find a solution. Could you help?

**EDIT**

'firmaListesi' Array

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58455d2d506c1cab1c82153c"),
    "value" : [ 
        ObjectId("58455d92506c1cab1c82153e"), 
        ObjectId("5847afe2506c912e6e3a72a7"), 
        ObjectId("5850f2e725108a44a813f93f"), 
        ObjectId("58523f272510fae3c1345547")
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58455d2d506c1cab1c82154c"),
    "value" : [ 
        ObjectId("5850f2e725108a44a813f93f"), 
        ObjectId("58523f272510fae3c1345547")
    ]
}
```

Comment: I'm curious about what was the decision behind making the `value` field in the `firmaListesi` collection an object and not an array.

Comment: It can be said to try everything while searching for a solution. :) If there is a solution as an array, I can convert it back to the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below aggregation pipeline. The below query will `$unwind` ( this step is not required for 3.4 version ) the `ObjectID's` from the `value` field of  `firmaListesi` collection followed by `$look`ing up these ObjectId in the `calisanSayisi` collection in to `b` array.

Next step is to `$unwind` `b` output array and followed by `$group`ing on  `firmaListesi` `_id` to push previous output values. Final step is to write to `firmalarId` collection.

```
db.firmaListesi.aggregate([
    {$unwind:"$value"},
    {$lookup: {
        from: "calisanSayisi",
        localField: "value",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "b"
    }},
    {$unwind: {path: "$b", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true}},
    {$group: {_id:"$_id", value:{$push:"$b"}}},
    {$out: "firmalarId"}
])
```